# Error running python mrjob word count example

Tags: python, mapreduce, emr, mrjob

I'm trying to run the example word count map reduce task using [mrjob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/). I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mr.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mrjob.job import MRJob
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob-0.4_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/job.py", line 39, in <module>
    from mrjob.launch import MRJobLauncher
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob-0.4_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/launch.py", line 32, in <module>
    from mrjob.options import add_basic_opts
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob-0.4_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/options.py", line 22, in <module>
    from mrjob.runner import CLEANUP_CHOICES
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob-0.4_dev-py2.7.egg/mrjob/runner.py", line 49, in <module>
    from mrjob.fs.local import LocalFilesystem
ImportError: No module named fs.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the maintainers. You should open a ticket on Github the next time you have an issue like this. We don't watch Stack Overflow at all.

We use the master branch for development. Tagged releases and files in PyPI are stable.

Please look at this ticket and respond with any further questions. https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/513

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error as well. Did you clone mrjob directly from the Git repository, as I initially did? If so, try using one of the [tagged](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/tags) versions, such as [v0.3.4.1](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/zipball/v0.3.4.1), which worked for me.